# Get content from pages with same meta_key from Database

Tags: custom-field, meta-query

I need help!

I'm doing this template page and I want to get content from pages with the same `meta_key`.
I want to display all pages thumbnails that has the value "red" in the `meta_key`.

The problem is that the meta_key value in the db is a string... I get nothing with this:

```
$Red = 'a:1:{i:0;s:9:"Red";}';
$Red = unserialize($Red);

$pages = get_pages(array('meta_key' => 'color', 'meta_value' => $red[0]));
 foreach ($pages as $page):

    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>
    <?php echo $page->post_title; ?>

    <?php echo $page->post_content; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet is full of errors.

- The serialized string is invalid, it's only 3 chars instead of 9, unserialization will not work, it will trigger an error.
- Variables are case sensitive, `$red` doesn't exist, it's `$Red`, this will trigger an error too.
- The `<?php ?>` tags are redundant and invalid since there already must be an opening PHP tag, ofcourse this will also trigger an error.

Also I don't understand why the meta value being a string should be a problem?

Works fine:

```
$red = 'a:1:{i:0;s:3:"Red";}';
$red = unserialize($red);

$pages = get_pages(array('meta_key' => 'color', 'meta_value' => $red[0]));
foreach($pages as $page)
{
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail');
    echo $page->post_title;
    echo $page->post_content;
}
```

Comment: I get `a:1:{i:0;s:9:"Red";}` from the mySQL db, i'dont made that up :) . My problem is that I dont get any results when i write this code. I get nothing putting out `'meta_value' => $red[0]));` from the code either.

Comment: I see, however that needs to be fixed if you must work with these serialized values. Instead of a variable, try using a hard coded value as a test, ie `'meta_value' => 'Red'`, also make sure that you are using the correct upper and lower case, ie that `color` is actually lower case, and `Red` is upper case in the database.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I fixed the string now, sonow it says only "red" in the database, i trying this but it wont work!
`<?php get_pages("meta_key=color&number=3&title_li=&"); ?>`
 but this work
`<?php wp_list_pages("meta_key=color&number=3&title_li=&"); ?>` do you know why get_pages dosent work for me

Comment: There are lots of possible reasons... the most obvious is that `wp_list_pages` passes some modified defaults to `get_pages`, specifically `exclude` and `hierarchical`, where `hierarchical` is set to `0` as opposed to `1` when using `get_pages` directly. `exclude` might be different in case filters are active for `wp_list_pages_excludes`. To find out what exactly is different, do a `var_dump` on `$r` in the `get_pages` and `wp_list_pages` functions.